# Execute Immediate not working,need help in syntax

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

When I am executing the below query, it is working:

```
CREATE TABLE  MySchema.AAA  ( INFOLINKPODID NVARCHAR2(50));
```

But when I am trying to execute the same using execute immediate:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '|| MySchema||'.AAA ( INFOLINKPODID NVARCHAR2(50));';
```

Getting below compilation error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE TABLE  " when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CREATE TABLE  " to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `dbms_output.put_line('CREATE TABLE '|| MySchema||'.AAA ( INFOLINKPODID NVARCHAR2(50));');` to see what is  going on

Comment: Good idea, that is giving error as Unknown Command.

Comment: What is the value of `MySchema`?  Perhaps `dbms_output.put_line('MySchema=' || MySchema);`

Comment: You'll also need to remove the semicolon from the string.  Although if that was the only error the error message would be different.

Comment: see basically schema name has to come dynamically in my case.

Comment: even removing semi-colon is also giving the same error, kind of clueless, such a simple query..but not able to execute!

Comment: What is the value of `MySchema`?

Comment: It could be anything, I have replaced that with actual schema name only, still same error.

Comment: In your test perhaps find it out. Perhaps comment out the line. The error may be before that line

Comment: You cannot execute `execute immediate` on its own. So you must have some framing code, PL/SQL block or stored procedure. I suggest you post your entire code here for us to see. There's no way you're going to get an answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

as per the comments, you need a framing block, but also the semi-colon at the end of the execute immediate string needs to be removed (or you will get an ORA-00911 invalid character error), like this:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE TEST (X NUMBER)';
end;
/
```

should work.